# A parabola by three points. Interpolation and Plotting

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot this simple line graph and generate a polynomial equation using `Mathematica`. Please help

values

```
x,      y
50,     281.5533333
300,    672.6133333
600,    445.4033333
```

Comment: If you are new to the software, it is all the more reason to read the documentation. So, at which point did you get stuck when you tried to do this by yourself? By the way, the title of your question could be better.

Comment: Create a list with data and then: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please show _some_ effort. I'm sure you'll get here the help you need after that.

Comment: [Fastest way to fit a parabola to a set of points.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039039/fastest-way-to-fit-a-parabola-to-set-of-points)